# Rank of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{u_{i}u_{i}^T}$?

Tags: matrices

Is rank of sum of $n$ rank-1 symmetric matrices of the form $u_{i}u_{i}^T$ at most $n-1$? This seems to be incorrect for the sum of 2 rank-1 matrices.
What is the minimum value (lower bound) of the maximum eigenvalye of the sum of these matrices? Is $\frac{1}{n-1}$ a tight lower bound?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that it is incorrect for $n=1$, too (even for $n=0$).  No, the rank can be as high as $n$, provided the matrices we're talking about are $m$-by-$m$ with $m\geq n$.  E.g., a diagonal matrix with $n$ of its diagonal entries equal to $1$, and the rest $0$, can be expressed in this way.  The rank is at most $n$, because the image is contained in the span of the $u_i$s.

To determine the minimum maximum eigenvalue would require some assumptions that aren't stated.  I guess you're talking about real matrices.  Is each $u_i$ assumed to be a unit vector?  If the $u_i$ were arbitrary, then taking $n=1$ and $u_1=0$ would give you $0$ for the maximum eigenvalue.  If they are (real) unit vectors, then when $n>0$ the maximum eigenvalue is at least $1$, and this minimum is achieved when $n=1$.